# Can't install multer-gridfs-storage with Next.JS

Tags: next.js, multer, gridfs, next.js13, multer-gridfs-storage

I have built a test NextJS app, called *njs-voice-rcd* using these commands:

```
% npx create-next-app@latest
    .....
% cd njs-voice-rcd
% npm i mongoose
```

From this point on, I am having issues trying to install *multer* and *multer-gridfs-storage.*

I tried several approaches but none is working.
There are always version conflicts somewhere.

I hope some with a better knowledge of the GridFS packages will be able to provide some pieces of advice.

**1) I tried to install multer first and then multer-gridfs-storage.**

```
% npm i multer              
    added 17 packages, and audited 391 packages in 1s

    134 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details

    found 0 vulnerabilities
% 

% npm i multer-gridfs-storage
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: njs-voice-rcd-2@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: multer@1.4.5-lts.1
    npm ERR! node_modules/multer
    npm ERR!   multer@"^1.4.5-lts.1" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
    npm ERR!   multer-gridfs-storage@"*" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! See /Users/me/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2023-08-04T07_47_41_122Z-debug-0.log
% 

% grep multer package.json                                                 
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
%
```

**2) I also tried to install multer-gridfs-storage first.**

```
% npm i multer-gridfs-storage                                              
    npm WARN deprecated @types/bson@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. bson provides       its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
    npm WARN deprecated multer@1.4.4: Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434. This is         fixed in v1.4.4-lts.1 which drops support for versions of Node.js before 6. Please      upgrade to at least Node.js 6 and version 1.4.4-lts.1 of Multer. If you need support        for older versions of Node.js, we are open to accepting patches that would fix the CVE     on the main 1.x release line, whilst maintaining compatibility with Node.js 0.10.

    added 50 packages, and audited 424 packages in 4s

    134 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details

    4 high severity vulnerabilities

    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force

    Run `npm audit` for details.
%
```

As one can see in either cases there are problems.

Is there any good way to handle this situation?